# Can't get HTML table to consistent width on all devices

Tags: android, html, css, ios

I'm trying to make a table width consistent on all devices so that there's no spillover to the right and outside of view on the mobile devices the site is loaded on. Here are two images to compare that show just two examples among dozens of different mobile devices (iOS and Android).

[image: Ideal Layout]

[image: Not Ideal Layout]

I've tried changing the table CSS to various degrees, including width, max-width, fixed, etc. But nothing seems to work. I thought that a simple compromise of a given width among all devices would do the trick, but width has no effect in any way. Almost like the width attribute is no longer recognized by browsers.

To get to this screen, add a product to the cart at https://intechrahealth.com/. This is the checkout page. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `font-size` is too big. If you shrink it, the entire table can shrink and fit right. Change this query here

```
@media (max-width: 479px)
  #content table.cart td, #content table.cart th, #content table.cart tr, table.cart
  td, table.cart th, table.cart tr {
    padding: .857em .287em!important;
  }
}
```

To this with responsive `font-size`

```
@media (max-width: 479px)
  #content table.cart td, #content table.cart th, #content table.cart tr, table.cart
  td, table.cart th, table.cart tr {
    padding: .857em .287em!important;
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, @Jack! I was so focused on what I thought was a simple width problem that it never occurred to me to change the font size. Hopefully it's still legible by people with eyesight issues, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it. Thank you again!